# Cannot start jupyter notebook after deleting anaconda

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda

- What happened:
  I have had Pip and Anaconda installed on my Mac. I tried to tidy up and decided to delete Anaconda since I assumed I only needed Pip for my Python programming.
- My question:
  I have been using jupyter notebook for my university project. Apparently, it had been installed by me using anaconda. Now that anaconda is gone, when I try running jupyter notebook, it is still looking in the deleted anaconda directory and throws the following error in the command line

/Users/username/anaconda3/bin/jupyter: No such file or directory

Furthermore, I now get this error when installing jupyter using pip3:

WARNING: The scripts jupyter, jupyter-migrate and jupyter-troubleshoot are installed in '/Users/username/Library/Python/3.8/bin' which is not on PATH.

Unfortunately, I barely have an idea of what I am doing when installing anything using the command line. Could you help me out in fixing the issue?

Comment: Try running `/Users/username/Library/Python/3.8/bin/jupyter-notebook`

Comment: thanks, that worked. Do I have to write this every time, or can I somehow reconfigure to the original "jupyter notebook"command I have always used?

Comment: Also, what does this warning mean, and  do I have to do something about it?    
 "The scripts jupyter, jupyter-migrate and jupyter-troubleshoot are installed in '/Users/username/Library/Python/3.8/bin' which is not on PATH."